# How to fix the repeating of the last element of the list and not showing the other elements of list?

Tags: python, loops, nested, inventory, receipt

```
cart = ['Fries','Nuggets','Chicken']
quantity = [1, 2, 3]
price = [123, 45, 65]
amount = 0

def Check_Inventory():
    print(f'Orders \t\t\t\t Qty. \t\t Price (php) \n')

    for count, mycart in enumerate(cart):
        while len(mycart) != 10:
            mycart += ' '

        else:
            carts = mycart

    for qty, prices in zip(quantity, price):
        print(f'{carts} \t\t\t {qty} \t\t {prices}')

    print(f'\n Total: \t\t\t\t\t {amount} \n')

Check_Inventory()
```

**EXPECTED:**

```
Orders                           Qty.            Price(php)

Fries                            1               123
Nuggets                          2               45
Chicken                          3               65

 Total:                                          0
```

**GET INSTEAD:**

```
Orders                           Qty.            Price(php)

Chicken                          1               123
Chicken                          2               45
Chicken                          3               65


Total:                                          0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that every time you loop through the cart, you are redefining the `carts` variable, so at the end, it only keeps what it was last defined.

[Yash Metha's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75168244/21021990) is basically there, but assuming you also want aligned spacing, you just need to modify the string formatting a little bit:

```
for crt,qty, prices in zip(cart,quantity, price):
        print(f'{crt:<10} \t\t\t {qty} \t\t {prices}')
```

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
for qty, prices in zip(quantity, price):
        print(f'{carts} \t\t\t {qty} \t\t {prices}')
```

to this:

```
for crt,qty, prices in zip(cart,quantity, price):
        print(f'{crt} \t\t\t {qty} \t\t {prices}')
```

**Updated part..**

Your answer. if there is any name in the `cart` which has **length greater than 10**. **The code tends to infinity**.

You can do like

```
cart = ['Fries','Nuggets','Chickenfried','Donuts']
quantity = [1, 2, 3, 4]
price = [123, 45, 65, 40]
amount = 0

def Check_Inventory():
    print(f'Orders \t\t\t\t Qty. \t\t Price(php) \n')
    
    max_length=max([len(i) for i in cart]) #Finding the max length in the cart
    for orders, qty, prices in zip(cart, quantity, price):
        while len(orders) != max_length:
            orders=orders+' '*(max_length-len(orders)) #Making all cart name same length by adding empty character
        else:
            print(f'{orders}  \t\t  {qty} \t\t\t {prices}')

    print(f'\nTotal: \t\t\t\t\t {amount} \n')

Check_Inventory()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
cart = ['Fries','Nuggets','Chicken']
quantity = [1, 2, 3]
price = [123, 45, 65]
amount = 0

def Check_Inventory():
    print(f'Orders \t\t\t\t Qty. \t\t Price(php) \n')

    for orders, qty, prices in zip(cart, quantity, price):
        while len(orders) != 10:
            orders += ' '
        else:
            print(f'{orders} \t\t\t {qty} \t\t {prices}')

    print(f'\n Total: \t\t\t\t\t {amount} \n')

Check_Inventory()
```

Comment: just wanted to ask let's say if cart contains a value. which length is greater than 10 than your code is going infinite loop...